# javascript code to display an alert message after 15 keystrokes

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In my project, there is a text box to enter the password and the password characters limit is up to 15. So, I want to display an alert message through javascript as soon as the user tries to enter the 16th character. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this on Javascript:

```js
document.getElementById("password").onkeyup = function() {

    var text = document.getElementById("password").value

    if(text.length> 15){
       alert("too much text")
    }


};
```

```html
<input id="password" type="password"  placeholder="password">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
function alrtMsg() {
    var x = document.getElementById("pwd").value;
    if(x.length > 16){
     alert("maximum length is 16");
     document.getElementById("pwd").value = '';
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<input type="password" id="pwd" onkeyup="alrtMsg()">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery:

```
$("#inputFieldId").on("input propertychange", function(){
    var val = this.value;
    if(val.length > 15) {
        this.value = val.substring(0,15);  //comment if you don't want to remove the 16th character
        alert("Maximum 15 characters allowed!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to mention your code what you tied. Anyway if you don't know try this code

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="myFunction(this)" maxlength="5">
<script>
function myFunction(e) {
var maxlen= e.maxLength;  
 if(e.value.length >= maxlen)
    alert("Max length is limited to" +maxlen );
}
</script>
```